# JPA CriteriaBuilder - not in a Collection

Tags: jpa, collections, where-clause

What is the difference between:

First test run on the Builder:

```
Predicate predicate = root.get(PersonEntity_.name).in(names);
criteriaBuilder.not(predicate);
```

Second test run on the Query:

```
Predicate predicate2 = root.get(PersonEntity_.name).in(names).not();
criteriaQuery.where(predicate2);
```

This seems to give the same results. Am I missing something? ***Should we choose the CriteriaBuilder above the CriteriaQuery?***

Complete example:

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
names.add("John");
names.add("Emma");

CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<PersonEntity> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(PersonEntity.class);
Root<PersonEntity> root = criteriaQuery.from(PersonEntity.class);

// First test run on the Builder
Predicate predicate = root.get(PersonEntity_.name).in(names);
criteriaBuilder.not(predicate);

// Second test run the query
//    Predicate predicate2 = root.get(PersonEntity_.name).in(names).not();
//    criteriaQuery.where(predicate2);

List<PersonEntity> list = entityManager.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```

Comment: I don't understand.  Both criteriaBuilder.not(predicate) and predicate.not() return a new predicate, and are equivalent.  But unless you call criteriaQuery.where(predicate2), neither should get added to the query.

Comment: I have updated the example: They are not run together, but put in comment and then run separatly

Comment: Right, but as I mentioned, both criteriaBuilder.not(predicate) and predicate.not() are supposed to just return a predicate as per the specification.  Check with your JPA provider to see if this is a bug, as I do not believe criteriaBuilder.not(predicate) should change the query.  You must associate the resulting predicate with the query somehow to be JPA portable.

Answer (score 1):

There is not difference between these variants. Both statements result in the same.